# Why Does the Devil Have a Silver Nose

Tags: the-devil, italy

I recently heard an Italian fairy-tale from a friend, in which a girl rescues her sisters from the Devil's basement. I've identified the tale as *How the Devil Married Three Sisters* (sometimes *Silver Nose* or *The Devil's Silver Nose*). No matter the title, in the story the Devil has a nose made out of silver. Is there a traditional explanation for this, or even other tales where it is mentioned? A peremptory google search and search of this Stack Exchange didn't find me anything besides various tellings and re-tellings of the same story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Italo Calvino mentioned in his *Italian Folktales* that the silver nose was rare even in Italian tales.

[But a silver nose was sometimes used as a prosthetic, when you lost a nose to syphilis.](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2012-11-3d-nose.html)  Hence, a silver nose is a sign of loose living.